# how can i use perl or grep for extracting all links in a file

Tags: perl

How can I get all the links from a file that has only one line.

For example file content :

```
ABC def WWW.----link_1----.html ARE ABC def WWW.---link_2----.html ABC def WWW.---link_3---.html
```

I have this command so far:

```
perl -pe 's/.*(WWW.*?.html).*/$1/' file_name
```

this only gives me:

```
WWW.---link_1-----.html
```

the output i want is each link in separate line  :

```
link_1  
link_2  
link_3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `/g` modifier to match every link occurrence,

```
perl -lne 'print for /(WWW.*?[.]html)/g' file_name
```

output

```
WWW.----link_1----.html
WWW.---link_2----.html
WWW.---link_3---.html
```

Comment: just wanted to check , since i have a huge file of around 5 GB, which command is efficient perl or grep to achieve what the above question

Comment: @waheebyaqub both are fast, and some kind of bench-marking would be required. You may also find that file IO performance could be bottleneck.

Comment: @waheebyaqub This is far from a real benchmark, but using `grep -P` with this regex is *significantly* slower on my machine than using mpapec's Perl one-liner (which makes sense; I would expect Perl to execute Perl regexes quickly). Since `-P` is the only way to specify a non-greedy match in `grep` (that I know of), Perl wins.